# Hash/string gets escaped

Tags: ruby, string, hash, escaping, sinatra

This is my hyperresource client:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'hyperresource'
require 'json'

api = HyperResource.new(root: 'http://127.0.0.1:9393/todos',                      
                    headers: {'Accept' => 'application/vnd.127.0.0.1:9393/todos.v1+hal+json'})
string = '{"todo":{"title":"test"}}'
hash = JSON.parse(string) 
api.post(hash)
puts hash
```

The hash output is: {"todo"=>{"title"=>"test"}}

At my Sinatra with Roar API I have this post function:

```
post "/todos" do
  params.to_json
  puts params
  @todo = Todo.new(params[:todo])
  if @todo.save  
    @todo.extend(TodoRepresenter)
    @todo.to_json 
  else 
    puts 'FAIL'
  end 
end
```

My puts 'params' over here gets: {"{\"todo\":{\"title\":\"test\"}}"=>nil}

I found out, these are 'escaped strings' but I don't know where it goes wrong.

EDIT:

I checked my api with curl and postman google extension, both work fine. It's just hyperresource I guess

Answer (score 0):

You are posting JSON, ergo you either need to register a Sinatra middleware that will automatically parse incoming JSON requests, or you need to do it yourself.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'hyperresource'
require 'json'

api = HyperResource.new(root: 'http://127.0.0.1:9393/todos',                      
                    headers: {'Accept' => 'application/vnd.127.0.0.1:9393/todos.v1+hal+json'})
string = '{"todo":{"title":"test"}}'
hash = JSON.parse(string) 
api.post({:data => hash})
puts hash    

---

post "/todos" do
  p = JSON.parse(params[:data])
  puts p.inspect
  @todo = Todo.new(p[:todo])
  if @todo.save  
    @todo.extend(TodoRepresenter)
    @todo.to_json 
  else 
    puts 'FAIL'
  end 
end
```

Should do what you need.

Comment: My client get's a 500 error. In the server console is why: "TypeError - no implicit conversion of nil into String:". So, I guess the :data try's to parse the nil part instead of the whole data hash @mcfinnigan